# Victim of Revenge Voting

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting-fraud

I had a feeling that I have been targeted by someone for taking out revenge by downvoting my previous answers/questions and it is not continuous as it only occurs in pair and that too at the same time. 
I suspect it as a revenge voting by some user. Is there any way this can be confirmed.

I have attached screenshot of my reputation tab.
[image]

Comment: I'm not really seeing a clear "revenge downvoting" pattern here? They're spread over a really long time. They could just be legitimate downvotes.

Comment: Just a second ago I have received 2 more downvotes.

Comment: I know downvotes sting, even if the reputation impact is microscopic. But... see Shog's answer in the duplicate link. Key quote: `If it's not particularly bothering you, then you could just take satisfaction in the belief that someone is slowly wasting their life on this and go spend your own doing something more productive.` If something gets downvoted totally unfairly, there's a huge chance someone will upvote and eradicate the effect of 5 downvotes. But feel free to flag for moderator attention if it really bothers you.

Comment: It is not related of getting some negative points but my main concern is that from next time I will be in doubt whether or not correct others wrong answer or questions just avoid this revenge voting. This has happened me in the past as well and today also I met in a case like this.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. That's really unfortunate. It may be not enough for moderators to act on yet... I'd go on, live with the uncertainty for the moment, and see what happens.

Comment: @VivekMishra the whole point of revenge is to hurt as many people as possible who directly or indirectly involved in the original event. So while your concern about vote count on posts no longer reflecting quality of the post is valid it is actually beneficial from person's on revenge rampage point of view - more people will suffer for whatever started the revenge.

Comment: same think for me, I responded politely to a provocative comment from a profile that had a lot of points, and since then, I haven't seen the light of day ... however, i give our time to help and contribute. I have no other reasons

Answer (score 4):

> I had a feeling that I have been targeted by someone for taking out
>   revenge by downvoting my previous answers/questions and it is not
>   continuous as it only occurs in pair and that too at the same time. I
>   suspect it as a revenge voting by some user. **Is there any way this
>   can be confirmed.**

Stack Exchange does have an algorithm that runs nightly and invalidates anything the system perceives as serial voting - up or downvoting.

So if someone downvotes loads and loads of your posts, chances are these votes will be reversed and/or the person will get a moderator message or suspension.

In your case though, these are few and isolated votes, and may not come from the same user.

My advice is to get over it, the couple of points of reputation you lost are nothing to fret over. If this really is a person doing this to upset you, then the best defense is to not get upset over it. Keep writing answers and questions and don't let it bother you.